# Trouble adding a newly created instance to ebs snapshot scheduler

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

EC2 EBS volumes are automatically performed daily and retained for 30 days which was handled by the AWS: EBS Snapshot Scheduler, https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/ops-automator/.

And there is an instance that was created recently and wanted to add this instance to create its ebs snapshot daily, but I couldn't find where/how to update this rule to the above configuration that was created previously.. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review Appendix D in the document for settings up the [Ops Automator](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/ops-automator/latest/ops-automator.pdf). It talks about how resources are identified for actions:

> The AWS Ops Automator uses a custom tag key (name) to identify
>   resources that will receive automated actions. The default tag key is
>   OpsAutomatorTaskList but you can modify it during initial
>   configuration of the solution’s AWS CloudFormation template. The value
>   of the OpsAutomatorTaskList tag contains a comma-separated list of
>   tasks you want the solution to perform on that resource.

This means you should have a tag on existing EBS volumes that identify them for actions as well as what those actions are. Each [action has an associated CloudFormation template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/ops-automator/latest/ops-automator.pdf), see Appendix A in the same PDF:

> The AWS Ops Automator automatically generates a separate AWS
>   CloudFormation template for each action. Review the template
>   parameters and modify them as necessary.

This same appendix also explains what each action template does. Starting with those regarding snapshotting.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have looked through the current template, but it seems like it is set as default and should include * instances, but automated snapshot is not running on this new instance :( I have added the current template to my question if it helps... thank you!

Comment: Did you check the old EBS volumes for tags?